# Which Function spends more time above the other in a given timeframe? And by how much?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, percentages

To make things easier to understand, let's use an example:
Function 1: y = x
Function 2: y = 5sin(5x)/(x)
Interval: 0 to 2

[Graph via FooPlot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UKte.jpg)

What I'm looking for is the percentage of time one is greater than the other (i.e. Function 2 is greater than Function 1 60% of the time).

I don't care much greater it is than the other function; just over the entire interval, which one was greater more often than the other.

A real-life application would be comparing your investment portfolio to a benchmark & seeing how often you were beating/losing to it (assuming you are crossing over/under it often).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let f(x) = Function1 - Function2 and create a sign graph.

Example:

Let f(x) = x - 5sin(5x)/x. Roots to this function between 0 and 2 (found with any graphing calculator) are 0.61, 1.33, and 1.75. So

```
       -         +         -        +        f(x)
```

<----|---------|-------------|---------------|-----------|---->  x

```
   0     0.61      1.33       1.75       2
```

If f(x) is positive, then Function1 > Function2.
If f(x) is negative, then Function2 > Function1.

The intervals over which f(x) is negative are 0 to 0.61 and 1.33 to 1.75.
Sum these intervals to get f(x) is negative for 1.03 units over the interval from 0 to 2 or 51.5% (100 * 1.03 / 2) of the interval. So Function2 is greater than Function1 51.5% of the time.

For the question of how much greater or less, you may need to be more specific in your question. I would say that the average value of the function ( $\frac{1}{b - a} \cdot \int_a^b f(x) \, dx$ ) would answer your question. If the $\int_0^2 x - \frac{sin(5x)}{x} \, dx $ is positive, then Function1 has more area than Function2. If the integral is negative, then Function2 has more area that Function1. In this case, the average value of f(x) is equal to -6.29 / 2 = -3.145 units. So Function2 is greater than Function1 by 3.145 units.

This answer assumes you are familiar with the concepts of sign graphs, definite integrals, and the average value of a function over an interval.

Comment: You should try posting here with proper formatting uniformly.

Comment: I am familiar with all the above things.  however, let's say that we use two different functions:
Function 1: y = 3sin(10x)/2x
Function 2: y = x
Interval: 0 to 5

Is there an easier way to calculate it when there are many interceptions between the two?

Or is that the only way it can be done?

Because in this example, it will just be overly tedious.

I'm sorry if I'm asking the question poorly also.  I'm mostly interested in the % of time one is above the other, not the amount.